# Hibernate: default transaction timeout with respect to custom @Transactional(timeout)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hikaricp

In my project, which is built on Spring Boot, Hibernate and PostgreSQL (with HikariCP), I would like to set up transaction timeout for the entire app -> I simply want all the transactions that take too long to be terminated because these transactions could be started by user request and it could easily end up with exhausting the entire connection pool.

I'm aware of some ways how to set up the default transaction timeout, e.g. by Spring Boot property `spring.transaction.default-timeout` or by setting `defaultTimeout` property on `HibernateTransactionManager`.
Both solutions work pretty well.

However, there are many places where the long transactions are ok in the project and I would like to have no timeout there (override the default behaviour). I've tried to use `@Transactional` with specified `timeout` parameter: `@Transactional(timeout = 10)` on these places but it does not override the default global value which is still used instead.

The worst way how to achieve my requirement is to define a custom annotation that would override `@Transactional` with default timeout and use this annotation in the entire project, which I would like not to do for many reasons.

Currently, I am not aware of any other solution. Isn’t there anything nicer?
Thanks.

Comment: Transaction without timeout is ok but what about request timeout? So imagine 1 hour transaction. DB will work but request timeout could happen

Comment: Long transactions that are ok in my project are not based on user requests but mostly synchronizations that are started e.g. by cron. That's why I don't want any timeout there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving the long-running jobs into a separate service application, in which you can set a longer transaction timeout.